# Selection of regressors into a regression model

Tags: regression, correlation, stepwise-regression

Why is it that backward selection/elimination as compared to forward selection of regressors, is often less adversely affected by the correlative structure of regressors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the forward selection, little-contributing terms selected in previous steps are not eliminated, resulting in the final model with less meaningful terms. This, however, does not alleviate the problem of diluted significance of collinear predictors, so if there is a reason to expect some of those predictors to have a meaningful effect, it won't be "less adversely affected".